# In AWS Athena - how to show the timestamp column with required format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a parquet file in AWS S3 with timestamp column as below

```
updated_time = "2014-11-13T03:10:17.098765Z".
```

I created a glue catalog and query it from AWS athena.

In Athena I can able to see only 3 precision value in milliseconds fields "2014-11-13 03:10:17.098". Is there any option to get all 6 precision value as same as in S3 as microseconds.

Actual result in Athena

```
2014-11-13 03:10:17.098
```

Expected result in Athena

```
2014-11-13 03:10:17.098765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto supports timestamp granularity up to milliseconds and not microseconds.
Since Athena is basically managed Presto, the Presto limitations are valid for Athena as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In AWS documentation for Athena timestamp datatype there mention as "Date and time instant in a java.sql.timestamp compatible format such as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.f.....]" since f is nano seconds. Let me know your thought on this.

Comment: Interesting, can you try `format_datetime(column, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff') from table`?

Comment: I'm getting error as "illegal pattern compenent : ffffff". But it will works in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'. the result becomes string and also the value is not correct it just append 000 in it like "2014-11-13 03:10:17.098000".

Comment: Then I was right I guess. Athena can't display microseconds.